# Определить нужный класс и заменить его

Tags: jquery

В общем есть блок, который имеет два класса, допустим выглядит так:

```
<div class="block class-A class-1"></div>
```

Скриптом можем менять первый и второй класс, вот только "изменить" можем так:

```
class-A -> class-A || class-B
class-1 -> class-1 || class-2 || class-3 || class-4
```

Скрипт на смену выглядит так:

```js
$('#changeOneClass').bind('change',function(){
  var thisValue = $(this).val();
  
  if(thisValue=='class-A') 
    $('.block')
      .removeClass('class-B')
      .addClass('class-A');
  else if(thisValue=='class-B') 
    $('.block')
      .removeClass('class-A')
      .addClass('class-B');
});

$('#changeOneClass').bind('change',function(){
  var oldThisValue = '',
      thisValue = $(this).val();
  // Вот тут уже сталкнулся с проблемой, которую хочу решить в вопросе.
  // Суть в том, что у меня реализованно "изменение" по другому, у меня ещё есть переменная "oldThisValue" - она является прошлым значением и потом получается так:
  $('.block')
      .removeClass(oldThisValue)
      .addClass(thisValue);
});
```

```css
.block {display: block; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 3px solid transparent;}

.class-A {background: red;}
.class-B {background: blue;}

.class-1 {border-color: yellow;}
.class-2 {border-color: green;}
.class-3 {border-color: gray;}
.class-4 {border-color: violet;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block class-A class-1"></div>

<select id="changeOneClass">
  <option>class-A</option>
  <option>class-B</option>
</select>

<select id="changeTwoClass">
  <option>class-1</option>
  <option>class-2</option>
  <option>class-3</option>
  <option>class-4</option>
</select>
```

Суть в том, что это изменение работает с LocalStorage и при загрузке оно подключается.
С первым вариантом (`class-A || class-B`) проще, я просто проверяю **`LocalStorage == class-A`** - то удаляю **`class-B`** и ставлю **`class-A`**

А как быть со вторым вариантом, где выборов больше?
В голову приходит только массив с `class-1, class-2, class-3, class-4`, потом проверить есть что-то в `.block` и если есть, то удалить этот класс и добавить другой, из LocalStorage.

**Важно**: вполне вероятно, что у `.block`, помимо `class-A` и `class-1` будут ещё какие-то классы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понял, при чем здесь `LocalStorage`.

```js
$('#changeOneClass,#changeTwoClass').change(function() {
  $(this).find("option").each(function() {
    $('.block').removeClass($(this).val());
  });
  $('.block').addClass($(this).val());

  localStorage.setItem(this.id, this.value);
});

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var v;

  v = localStorage.getItem("changeOneClass");
  if (v)
    $("#changeOneClass").val(v);
  $("#changeOneClass").change();

  v = localStorage.getItem("changeTwoClass");
  if (v)
    $("#changeTwoClass").val(v);
  $("#changeTwoClass").change();
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}

.class-A {
  background: red;
}

.class-B {
  background: blue;
}

.class-1 {
  border-color: yellow;
}

.class-2 {
  border-color: green;
}

.class-3 {
  border-color: gray;
}

.class-4 {
  border-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block class-A class-1"></div>

<select id="changeOneClass">
  <option>class-A</option>
  <option>class-B</option>
</select>

<select id="changeTwoClass">
  <option>class-1</option>
  <option>class-2</option>
  <option>class-3</option>
  <option>class-4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Уверен вы знаете что делает LocalStorage, так вот, в моём случае он сохраняет классы для этого блока и при обновление страницы они подгружаются как и были до этого. Проблема в том, что я могу подгрузить `class-A`, ибо там проще "проверить" какой класс заменить (пример в вопрос), а вот с `class-1` мне сложнее разобраться, ибо их больше. Надеюсь понятно объясняю, спать охота)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 Сохраняйте `.val()` для обоих селектов. При чтении - вызывайте `.val(...)` для обоих селектов с соответствующими прочитанными значениями. Потом вызывайте `$('#changeOneClass,#changeTwoClass').change();`

Comment: типо `setLocalStorage('bla-bla','class-A class-1')` и приняв это ставить в `.block`?

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 Нет. Добавил код.

Comment: В общем ладно, башка не варит, но сделал иначе и получил то что хотел :D Спасибо за помощь, отмечу как правильный)